# Different url to same page (with dynamic content)

Tags: urls, parameter

I have a custom php script that in a specific page of my wordpress website is generating a dynamic content (ie. page "mysite.com/citydetail" that will load a list of places specific for that city).

The script is very simple, the source page (ie. "mysite.com) has a link to "mysite.com/citydetail" passing some parameters (via POST form). The page retrieves the parameters and, after a query into my database, print the content page.

I would like to avoid to have the same page (ie. "mysite.com/citydetail") with different content, in terms of SEO and google crawler probably is not the the best choice.. and I'm here to ask you the best way to proceed. I have permalink enabled.

I could do it adding parameter in the url like "mysite.com/citydetail/**?city=paris**" even if I'll not use that parameter (I pass the cityID via POST method).In this scenario I can have a list of "different" url containing the name of the city to which the contents page refer to.

Do you see any negative aspect using this approach?Do you see valid alternatives I could use?

The main target is to avoid problem with my website and be sure my contents are properly indexed in google search.

Comment: You’re misusing the POST method, and your solution doesn’t solve the problem if you’re using a POST request, because a search engine isn’t going to send a post request when indexing or linking to the city URL. You should populate the page based on the URL parameter. If you have a form that should redirect to the populated page on submission then use the GET method on the form.

Comment: Thanks Jacob.  You agree, not using the url to navigate also google cannot index properly. I could use GET as well passing the "idcity" in a format like this "mysite.com/citydetail/?idcity=123". Is this url format valid for google? Could make sense to add also another parameter with the cityname (ie: ""mysite.com/citydetail/?idcity=123&cityname=paris" ..even if not necessary to me) in order to have "better" url for google indexing?